# C++ IOS extra characters

Tags: c++

Can anyone please tell me why the following (admittedly useless) code results in a file with ascii 64 in it?

```
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ofstream qFile("test");
   qFile << std::ios::left;
}
```

Comment: Running it I get the "32", regardless of the last line `qFile << std::setw(20)`

Comment: I get the string "32" as well.

Comment: And it doesn't matter that it's a file, you can use `cout` and still same result...

Comment: Hope you don't mind my tinkering, but your initial post wasn't even a valid program, so I've left a real testcase of your problem up there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::ios::left` is not a manipulator, it is a format flag with a specific value (that being 32 on my implementation). On GCC 4.8 I'm getting 32 as the output, but your implementation must differ in the way it sets the value of the flag.

The manipulator you are looking for is `std::left`:

```
std::ofstream qFile("test");
qFile << std::left;
qFile << std::setw(20);
```

Comment: +1: Yes, that's it. Compare [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) with [`std::ios::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags)